# How to get attributes of a link using attachListener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have tried both jQuery and JavaScript, but none is able to bring attribute of link. Here is the code I am using- this is not printing anything in `callme` function's alert

```
function callMe() {
    var ll = this;    
    var id1 = ll.getAttribute('id');
    alert('Inside callMe...'+id1);
    }

    function load() {   
     var lnk = new Array();
     lnk = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
     var len = lnk.length;
    
    for (var i=5;i<len;i++){
    var id = lnk[i].getAttribute('data-id');
    lnk[i].attachEvent('onclick',callMe);
    }
}
```

I tried using following jQuery too

```
$("a").click(function(){
alert(this.id); 
var shouldTrack = $(this).attr('id');
alert('Inside callMe...'+shouldTrack); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> function callMe() {
>   var ll = this;
```

When using the MS proprietary [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the called listener's *this* keyword is not set to the element on which the listener was called (as is when the W3C [addEventListener](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) method or a HTML intrinsic event handler is used). There are a number of fixes for that, the usual one is to use the associated *event* object, so the function becomes:

```
function callMe(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  var ll = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

>   var id1 = ll.getAttribute('id');
```

There is no need to use *getAttribute* for standard DOM properties:

```
    var id1 = ll.id;
```

.

```
>   alert('Inside callMe...'+id1); 
> }
> 
> function load() {
>   var lnk = new Array();
>   lnk =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

There is not much point to creating an array and assigning it to *lnk* only to immediately replace it with the NodeList returned by *getElementsByTagName*. Also, you seem to be after links, so better to access the *document.links* collection which is already available and only includes links whereas *getElementsByTagName('a')* will include all A elements, including anchors.

So the above two lines can be:

```
    var lnk = document.links;
```

.

```
>   var len = lnk.length;
> 
>   for (var i=5; i<len; i++) {
>     var id = lnk[i].getAttribute('data-id');
>     lnk[i].attachEvent('onclick',callMe);
```

As noted above, *attachEvent* is a proprietary MS method that is not supported by all browsers. Better to have a function that first tries the W3C *addEventListener* method, then *attachEvent*. A very simple version is:

```
function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
  }
}
```

Noting that the event is the equivalent HTML intrinsic event name without the leading 'on'. So attaching the listener becomes:

```
      addEvent(lnk[i], 'click', callMe);
```

.

```
>   }
> }
```

Also, the function should be run after the document is ready, so either use the body's onload attribute, *window.onload* or put the script just before the closing body tag.

Lastly, don't forget to call *load*. Here is the entire script refactored:

```
<a href="#" id="link0">Link0</a>
<a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4">Link4</a>
<a href="#" id="link5">Link5</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
  }
}

function callMe(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  var ll = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  var id1 = ll.id;
  alert('Inside callMe...'+id1); 
}

function load() {
  var lnk = document.links;
  var len = lnk.length;

  for (var i=5; i<len; i++) {
    var id = lnk[i].getAttribute('data-id');
    addEvent(lnk[i], 'click', callMe);
  }
}

load();

</script>
```

Comment: That was ecellent explaination! Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this code before the page has finished loading? Either this must be at the end of the `</body>` or called on a `window.onload` or (in jQuery) the `$(document).ready`

Also attachevent isn't cross browser.

## [And this works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/VAygx/2/)

.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now I need jQuery equivellent for the following. Please help.                                          var request = document.getElementById('request_' + id1), response = document.getElementById('response_' + id1); modifyText(request.firstChild.nodeValue, response.firstChild.nodeValue);